# JPA invalid user/password inside multithreads

Tags: multithreading, jpa

I'm having an issue with JPA in multithreads application. I'm using JPA proxy authentication to access the database. Everything runs fine in session beans but when in java thread `run()` method, I cannot use `@EJB` so I use Initialcontext to look up the bean. When the program executes, I'm getting invalid username/password; logon denied.

```
@Stateless
public class MyDAO{
     @PersistenceContext(name="myPU")
     private EntityManager em;
     public MyEntity getData(String id){
         return em.find(MyEntity.class, id);
     }
     @AroundInvoke
     public Object setSessionUser(InvocationContext ctx){
       if(ctx.getTarget() instanceof MyDAO){
         Map properties = new HasMap();
         properties.put("eclipselink.oracle.proxy-type", OracleConnection.PROXYTYPE_USER_NAME);
         properties.put(OracleConnection.PROXY_USER_NAME, "myusername");
         properties.put("eclipselink.jdbc.exclusive-connection.mode", "Always");
         properties.put("eclipselink.jdbc.exclusive-connection.is-lazy", "false");
         ((org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl)em.getDelegate()).setProperties(properties);
         }
         return ctx.proceed();
    }
}
```

inside run();

```
@Override
public void run(){
   ...
   MyDAO dao = (MyDAO) new InitialContext().lookup("java:module/...");
   EntityObject obj = dao.getData("123456");
   ...
}
```

Comment: You must achieve the EntityManager with **@PersistentContext** but not **@EJB**

Comment: sorry it was a typo. it shoud be @PersistentContext(name="myPu")

Comment: My best guess is that because JTA is container managed and since java thread is not. Anyways, I solved my problem by calling a servlet inside the thread